# Refreshing microservice data with event messages

Tags: rest, apache-kafka, microservices, messaging

I am working on a microservice architecture where we are adding event based updates e.g.

1. user updates domain object in UI
2. UI sends message update to microservice A that manages that domain object.
3. Microservice A will publish an update message to a Kafka topic. The message will be the ID of the domain object updated, and the operation e.g. PUT/POST/DELETE.
4. Consumer microservices B, C, etc will listen to this topic and then have to call the appropriate domain object endpoint with the ID to retrieve the updated data.

The issue i'm wondering how to solve is step 4. We were planning on putting a enum in the Kafka message  that identifies the type of object that was updated since Microservice A handles a few similar types of the domain object that could be updated. The consumers would call the appropriate endpoint based on this type.

I think this isn't too great since each consumer has to do this check and call the endpoint. Any recommendations for a better approach?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In microservices architecture, each service owns it data and no other service can directly talk to other service's database.

In your case case, if A modifies a domain object that A owns and B, C etc. need those details, then B,C services have to call A's API to get that data. They can not talk to A's DB directly. B and C should not copy or replicate the data on their respective DBs as that defeats the benefits of microservices architecture.

Typically, B and C would need some subset of attributes for that domain model and those should ideally get passed through the message payload as events via Kafka topics.

For instance, if A is maintaing Customer Data and B needs customer address and credit limit then A should just pass customer address and credit limit via events to B. If B needs access to full Customer Data then B should call a Rest API on A to get those details.

Comment: Thanks for reply. The bit I am not sure on is when B needs to get data from A, is there a clean way for B to know what endpoint to call? I was thinking of passing a enum in the message that it would check to determine which endpoint but I don't think this is clean.

Comment: I would recommend to pass the necessary details from A to B via the Kafka event itself, as explained in the address and credit limit example. This saves you from an additional round trip from B to A and helps performance. Also, this is ideal and clean in most cases.  You can configure different topics to get different information/events as per the logic. If you still want to send both event (A->B) and then have B query A via REST endpoint then I would suggest putting the URI (not URL) in the event (A->B) itself. So, B would know which endpoint to call precisely. This is what HATEOS also does.

Comment: Ok. I think we will need to go with second option i.e. not sending data in the event due to the potential size of the event data. I was also thinking about adding the URI in the event so that the service just needs to call it. Only issue I can see is that how would the service know what type to deserialise the response to?

Comment: 1. If the event data is too huge then pls verify the boundaries of your microservices. The data should not be duplicated but only some attributes should be shared between services. 2. The size of the data remains same whether you pass through event or through REST. Default max size for kafka is 1MB. 3. Still, if you want to do REST, you can pass the Content-Type information in the event along with URI.